# Error al iniciar python en visual studio code

Tags: vscode

Acabo de instalar Visual Studio Code en mi ordenador y estoy teniendo problemas para instalarlo relacionados con el ipykernel.
Me indica que tengo que hacer un force-reinstall (lo habitual).
Pero me salta este error:

'''WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000280708F8990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/ipykernel/'''

¿Alguien me puede decir el motivo y como solucionarlo?

Gracias